# Round User Image size in G+ Android app

Tags: android

I posted this question on google plus but never got a response.  I'm creating an app with a nav drawer that displays user info.  I'm trying to mimic the drawer header found on the google plus or hangouts android apps.

I've got it all down.  Only thing I need is the size of the round user image they use.  I've googled for it but can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own by extending `ImageView` and overiding the `onDraw` method

Comment: Thank you.  I am able to create it, I just wanted to know if there is a recommended size.  I was unable to find one in the guildelines